# ScrollableResult show wrong totalRecords to compare with hql result and getResultList()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sql-server-2012, hql

I'm quite new for Hibernate and this is first time to post on StackOverFlow 's forum. I have table A, B and C as following below

As condition: C have foreignKey of B and B have foreignKey of A.

**Table A**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable {

   private int aId;
   private String aName;
   private List<B> bf= new ArrayList<B>();

   public A() {
   }

   public A(int aId, String aName) {
      this.aId= aId;
      this.aName= aName;
   }

   @Id

   @Column(name = "A_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
   public int getAId() {
      return this.aId;
   }

   public void setAId(int aId) {
      this.aId= aId;
   }

   @Column(name = "A_NAME", nullable = false)
   public String getAName() {
      return this.aName;
   }

   public void setAName(String aName) {
      this.aName = aName;
   }

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "bf")
   public Set<B> getBF() {
      return this.bf;
   }

   public void setBF(Set<B> bf) {
      this.bf = bf;
   }
}
```

**Table B**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B implements Serializable {

   private int bId;
        private String bName;
   private A af;
   private List<C> cf= new ArrayList<C>();

   public B() {
   }

   public B(int bId, String bName) {
      this.bId= bId;
      this.bName= bName;
   }

   @Id

   @Column(name = "B_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
   public int getBId() {
      return this.bId;
   }

   public void setBId(int bId) {
      this.bId= bId;
   }

   @Column(name = "B_NAME", nullable = false)
   public String getBName() {
      return this.bName;
   }

   public void setBName(String bName) {
      this.bName = bName;
   }

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
   public A getAF() {
      return this.af;
   }

   public void setAF(A af) {
      this.af= af;
   }         

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "cf")
   public Set<C> getCF() {
      return this.cf;
   }

   public void setCF(Set<C> cf) {
      this.cf= cf;
   }
}
```

**Table C**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class C implements Serializable {

   private int cId;
        private String cName;
   private B bf;

   public C() {
   }

   public C(int cId, String cName) {
      this.cId= cId;
      this.cName= cName;
   }

   @Id

   @Column(name = "C_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
   public int getCId() {
      return this.cId;
   }

   public void setCId(int cId) {
      this.cId= cId;
   }

   @Column(name = "C_NAME", nullable = false)
   public String getCName() {
      return this.cName;
   }

   public void setCName(String cName) {
      this.cName = cName;
   }

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
   public B getBF() {
      return this.bf;
   }

   public void setBF(B bf) {
      this.bf= bf;
   }
}
```

**I use ScrollableResults class to get total Records for performance improvements.**

```
ScrollableResults resultScroll = query.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE).scroll();
resultScroll.last(); // get last records
int totalRecords = resultScroll.getRowNumber() + 1;
if (resultScroll != null)
    resultScroll.close();
```

**If i use first hql, scrollableResults show 31 total records as show below**

```
Select at from A at inner join fetch at.bf
```

**If i use second hql, scrollableResults show 38 total records as shown below**

```
Select at from
     A at inner join fetch at.bf bt
     inner join fetch bt.cf
```

**If i use third hql, scrollableResults show correct total records, it is 31 records as shown below.**

```
Select at from
     A at inner join fetch at.bf bt
     inner join bt.cf
```

> If i use getResultList method, it always get 31 records. I think that scroll() has something wrong with two-level fetch but it work both of
>   one-level fetch and without fetch.

For additional information:

-Hibernate 5.2.2-Final

-Microsoft SQL Server 2012

-JDBC Driver: sqljdbc4 version 3.0

Thank you

Comment: I forgot DISTINCT keyword in my post and above results came from DISTINCT command. ^^

Comment: From my workaround to skip this problem but i still use ScrollableResults I have to createQuery 2 times. 
1) create hql without join fetch for getting totalRecord from ScrollableResults.
2) create hql with join fetch to retrieve data.